# WPF - how can I programmatically allow a control to find its desired size when it is never drawn on the screen (for a screenshot)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to programmatically take a screenshot of a control that I will never actually display on the screen (it is a duplicate of a control is shown in a different area of the application - this area is just writing a report).

I can set the control size to a fixed size using the following code:

```
Size renderSize = new Size(1000, 1000);
chartControl.Measure(renderSize);
chartControl.Arrange(new Rect(renderSize));
chartControl.UpdateLayout();
```

This correctly sets the size of the control to 1000x1000, but unfortunately the height of the control can vary - so I either risk losing a part of the picture, or include a region of blank canvas just to make sure.

I've tried various different approaches, but what I really want is something like:

```
chartControl.Resize("Auto");    // Pseudo code
chartControl.UpdateLayout();
```

Does anybody know a practical way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify: at present the UserControl "chartControl" is currently never added to any container.  I'm happy for that to remain the case, or to create a dummy container (like a Window) if this can "trick" WPF into sizing the UserControl...

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to @Lennart for pointing me in the right direction for this:

It seems that DesiredSize is only available (i.e. not (0,0)) after the Measure call has been made, but *after* the Measure call, the Desired size is the **minimum** of the control's actual desired size and the size that it has been given in the Measure call.  My original effort set the Measure too small, so I never found out the true desired size of the chartControl.

From this, the following ought to work:

```
Size renderSize = new Size(2000, 2000);
chartControl.Measure(renderSize);
chartControl.Measure(chartControl.DesiredSize);
chartControl.Arrange(new Rect(renderSize));
chartControl.UpdateLayout();
```

However, the second call to Measure doesn't have any affect - the ActualWidth and height after the first call becomes 2000, but doesn't get updated on the second call to Measure.

The work-around would be to destroy the original chartControl once its DesiredSize has been determined, and then create a new one using the previously determined DesiredSize.  It seems a bit clunky, though...

Comment: Can't you override the MeasureOverride() method of your chart control to calculate its size by yourself?

Comment: `Visibility.Hidden` hides the control, but reserves the space it occupies in the layout. so there should not be a problem using an invisible form and have it layouted just like its visible counterpart.

Comment: If you want to set the control to the size of the container class you can set the horizontal & vertical alignment to stretch & all margins to 0

Comment: Sorry: to try to answer all 3 points:  Lennart: the control doesn't necessarily know what size it needs to be - I'm happy for the standard WPF sizing routines to work that out from the components. dlatikay: I think that being hidden isn't the problem - I just can't find the right combination of settings to get a parent Window to size itself and its contents programmatically. PaulF: I don't necessarily *need* a container object as such - so long as I can persuade the chartControl to tell me its preferred size (the DesiredSize=(0,0)).

Comment: Can you check if `chartControl.DesiredSize` has a correct value after your Measure call, but before the Arrange?

Comment: Hello @Lennart.  Interestingly, the DesiredSize just after the Measure actually looks like the real desired size.  It wasn't originally, but I expanded my "canvas" to be oversized, and I think that's allowed the DesiredSize to expand to its genuine desired size.  I'll try it.

Comment: `DesiredSize` is exactly what you are looking for. If a UIElement has something like an "auto" size, you would get it from the DesiredSize property after calling Measure.

Comment: I've added a second edit after trying what I really thought was a solution.  It appears Measure is ignored on subsequent calls, so I can' resize chartControl once I'v called Measure the first time.

Comment: Sorry: my fault - I was sending the old renderSize to Arrange, so it over-rode my settings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Lennart for pointing me in the right direction for this, and everyone else who gave pointers:

It seems that DesiredSize is only available (i.e. not (0,0)) after the Measure call has been made, but *after* the Measure call, the Desired size is the **minimum** of the control's actual desired size and the size that it has been given in the Measure call.  My original effort set the Measure too small, so I never found out the true desired size of the chartControl.

This appears to work:

```
Size overSize = new Size(2000, 2000);    // Something oversized.
chartControl.Measure(overSize);
chartControl.Arrange(new Rect(chartControl.DesiredSize));
chartControl.UpdateLayout();

// Take a screenshot of the chart control
BitmapSource bitmapSource = ScreenshotHelper.CreateScreenshot(chartControl, new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)chartControl.ActualWidth, (int)chartControl.ActualHeight));
```